# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow - How to change Approval Status on "Create list item"

Tags: approval

I'm going to reconfigure some workflows on one site. This site and related workflows has been created by other person. Here is one example of the workflow. This workflow is use on the list with Content Approval option. When conditions in step are true it creates new item on another list with Approval Status set to Draft.

[image]

When I was trying to modify this field I don't see Approval Status as selectable column/field. It is blank but I can pick other values for Approval Status.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how this workflow has been created to allow me change Approval Status to Draft or Scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *"Update List Item"* action to update value in second list and you need only one workflow in first list. I have create a test workflow for you and you need to run this workflow when item is changed event (see image below).

[image]

**You can get reference with this two links,**

[Update an Item in another List with a Workflow in SharePoint 2010](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e965512-9d1d-40ac-9370-31e289401479/update-an-item-in-another-list-with-a-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

[SharePoint Designer 2007 Workflow - Update item in another list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/253e2758-1042-4d2d-801f-934833d7e901/sharepoint-designer-2007-workflow-update-item-in-another-list?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Sharepoint Designer? If not, [you can get it free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573).

What you can do is edit it in Designer (or create a new one in Designer).

Workflows > List Workflow > [choose your list] > give it a name (and maybe a description) > Action > Set Content Approval Status (under 'List Actions') > Set status and give comments > Save.

On that workflow's 'homepage' (Workflows > [the workflow you just created]), under start options (on the right), un-check 'Allow this workflow to be manually started' and check 'Start workflow automatically when an item is created'. Save the workflow and Publish.

Comment: As you can see on the screen shoots I use Sharepoint Designer. This workflow starts when item is changed. The main problem is I can't find how this Approval Status field is picked in this specified example on action "Create List Item". When I create a new workflow this field (Approval Status) is not selectable field (not visible) on action "Create List Item".

Comment: I can't see the screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a workflow columns button in the menu of SPD. This  contains columns that are added to the list automatically when the workflow is being attached. You should find the column and values there.